# How to deploy a Azure Function on Linux using Java code using Azure DevOps Pipelines?

Tags: java, azure-devops, azure-functions, continuous-deployment

Using the offered templates in Azure Pipelines I have configured the build and deploy of a C# based function to a Azure Function on Windows.
Now I need to do the same but with a Java function.

In the "Set up build", it offer only a template to "Node.js Function to Az Function in Linux", but I want to build and deploy the Java Function (Maven - Java 8) and deploy to a Az Function in Linux.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B3dVj.png)

Some tip about this task?

I tried to create a new pipeline based in templates in Azure Devops, but not found a option for that I need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To build your app, you may use maven with your function app pom file...

[image]

Then copy your build result to the build artifacts:

[image]

After that, you may deploy it in the release pipelines. To do that, create a service connection to your Resource Group in Azure Subscription: [Create an Azure Resource Manager service connection using automated security](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/library/connect-to-azure?view=azure-devops#create-an-azure-resource-manager-service-connection-using-automated-security)

and deploy it through Azure Functions task.

[image]

Comment: I will try this and report here if have success. Thank you!